# How to put callback into res.json in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback

I need to call asynchronous callback function that return object in my Express.js, but I don't know how!

```
app.get('/first', function (req, res, next) {

res.json(//put my async callback function here ?);
});
```

The function:

```js
const reqObj = () => {
  request(`isdb.pw/${url}`, function(err, res, body) {
    if (!err) {
      const $ = cheerio.load(body);
      var name = $('meta[name="description"]').attr('content');
      var story = $('meta[property="og:video:url"]').attr('content');
      return {
        name,
        story
      };
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: @KolaCaine but my function don't return promise, how i can use .then ?

Comment: Please post your function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make the function return a Promise, then you can use .then on it:

```js
const reqObj = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(`isdb.pw/${url}`, function(err, res, body) {
      if (!err) {
        const $ = cheerio.load(body);
        var name = $('meta[name="description"]').attr('content');
        var story = $('meta[property="og:video:url"]').attr('content');
        resolve({
          name,
          story
        });
      } else {
        reject(err);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

After that call the asynchronous function and run `res.json()` once you have the data:

```
app.get('/first', function (req, res, next) {
  reqObj().then(data => {
    res.json(data);
  }).catch(err => console.log(err)); 
});
```

`res.json()` only accepts Objects as it's parameter

---

Here is a solution with callbacks

```js
const reqObj = (callback) => { // <-- add callback parameter here
    request(`isdb.pw/${url}`, function(err, res, body) {
      if (!err) {
        const $ = cheerio.load(body);
        var name = $('meta[name="description"]').attr('content');
        var story = $('meta[property="og:video:url"]').attr('content');
        callback(null,{ // <-- call callback function without err, but with data
          name,
          story
        });
      } else {
        callback(err); // <-- call callback just with data
      }
    });
  });
};


app.get('/first', function(req, res, next) {
  reqObj((err, data) => { // <-- pass callback function
    if(err) return console.log(err) // <-- check for error
    res.json(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: Please accept the answer, if it helped you solve your problem :-)

Comment: but its posible to use callbacks without promises in this situation ?

Comment: Yes, but it will be a little more complicated... Are you targeting a node version that doesn't have Promise support?

Comment: i started learn JS about month ago, and i'm want to try everything for my knowledge )

Comment: I'll make an edit to the post explaining how you could do it with callbacks.

Comment: it will be great :)

Comment: Done. It's not that much longer, but you have to make a little adjustment